# Evaluating the Gauss linking integral of a Hopf link directly

Tags: multivariable-calculus, knot-theory

How does one go about evaluating the double integral
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin(s) - \sin(t) - \sin(s)\sin(t)}{\big(3 + 2(\sin(s) - \sin(t) - \sin(s)\sin(t))\big)^{3/2}}\,ds\,dt ?
$$

It seems like one should be able to evaluate this integral through a combination of trig identities and change of variables. If that is the case, I haven't found the right ones yet.

This integral is the [Gauss linking integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number#Gauss%27s_integral_definition) for the Hopf link. The linking number of a two-component link with components parameterized by $\gamma_1, \gamma_2 \colon S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is equal to the integral
$$ 
\frac{1}{4\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(\gamma_2(s) - \gamma_1(t)) \cdot (\gamma_1'(s) \times \gamma_2'(t)}{\| \gamma_1(s) - \gamma_2(t)\|^3}\,ds\,dt.
$$
To arrive at the integral in question, I parameterized the Hopf link by
$$
\gamma_1(s) = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(s)\\
\sin(s)\\
0
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad 
\gamma_2(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
\sin(t) - 1\\
\cos(t)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and simplified.

I understand that the linking number of the Hopf link parameterized above is $-1$  by combinatorial considerations -- and therefore the integral in question is $-4\pi$ -- but I am curious to see if this integral can be evaluated directly.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use periodicity to translate the bounds of integration somewhat $(s\mapsto s +3\pi/2,t\mapsto t-3\pi/2)$ then $\sin t\to -\cos t, \sin s\to \cos s$. This has the advantage of being even with respect to both $s$ and $t$, which may provide some benefit.